# ServiceStack JsonServiceClient: The requested resource does not support http method GET

Tags: http, http-post, servicestack, asp.net-web-api2

So I recently remade my API and client in a new solution on a different version control scheme. Some of the code has change, but nothing related to the JsonServiceClient. Anyways, I'm getting this exception stating `405 Method Not Allowed Code: Method Not Allowed, Message: The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.`

The issue is that the request is not a `GET` but a `POST`, I'm not sure where its getting mixed up. The actual post is represented as such:

```
var result = (
                    await
                        webService.PostAsync(new Login
                        {
                            Token = token,
                            Provider = provider,
                            IsLinkedAccount = isLinkedAccount,
                            ResponseText = responseText,
                            Uuid = uuid,
                            Platform = platform
                        }))
```

The `Login` DTO is represented as this:

```
[Route("/login", "POST")]
public partial class Login
    : IReturn<LoginDTO>
{
    public virtual string Token { get; set; }
    public virtual SocialNetworks Provider { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsLinkedAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual string ResponseText { get; set; }
    public virtual string Uuid { get; set; }
    public virtual Platform Platform { get; set; }
}
```

And the actual API route is represented as this:

```
public class LoginController : ApiController
{
    [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
    public async Task<LoginDTO> Login(Login request)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And I've used swagger and postman to verify that the endpoint is indeed accurate and I can manually send an HTTP POST, so what messed up with the JsonServiceClient?

These is the service stack versions I'm using

```
<package id="ServiceStack.Client" version="4.0.52" targetFramework="net452"/>
<package id="ServiceStack.Common" version="4.0.52" targetFramework="net452"/>
<package id="ServiceStack.Interfaces" version="4.0.52" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="ServiceStack.Text" version="4.0.52" targetFramework="net452" />
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be using ServiceStack Clients to call Web API Services. But the behavior doesn't sound right, can you update your question to include the full HTTP Request/Response Headers that gets actually sent using Fiddler.

Comment: I recently switched over from using servicestack to WebApi, but I really liked the JsonServiceClient so I wanted to keep it. It had been working fine with the webapi architecture up until this point. As for getting the full HTTP Request that will be a bit tricky since the application is run on an iPhone. I've been having problems getting that to work